# How to make indicator-network work with DSL?

Tags: indicator

I installed indicator-network on maverick and it shows only Ethernet with no option to add a DSL connection.I am using pppoeconf currently(could be the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indicator-network` works with [ConnMan](http://connman.net/about) instead of NetworkManager, and judging from their site ConnMan doesn't support PPP currently (it could be added with a plugin, if one exists).  (Also, this indicator is only going to be used for the Netbook Edition, not for the Desktop Edition.)